# Wordpress widget that stays there without reloading on page navigation

Tags: wordpress, widget

Is there a way to make a Wordpress widget stay there if a user clicks a link? I created a music player which should play without stopping when the user clicks on a link in Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

NO, but You can place on TOP . add `z-index:999;` and `position:fixed;` in your music player's .css file